# How can I pass a list from form1 to form2 to access it in a ButtonEvent in form2?

Tags: c#, winforms

I can access it only outside methods. But I want to use in a ButtonEvent.

Comment: Hi Rob, Welcome to stackoverflow, kindly provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1):

Create **list1** globally in **Form1**:

```
public List<string> list1 = new List<string>();
```

Create **list2** In **Form2** globally or locally and assign to it **list1**:

```
List<string> list2 = new List<string>();

Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
list2 = frm1.list1;
```